# How to set a margin using pack() in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm using **Java Swing** to set up the view of my application. After inserting all components I call the `frame.pack()` method to properly set the window's size.

Is there a way to **setup a margin between the border of the window and the contents of the Frame** using at the same time the `pack()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `JPanel` as the content pane of the frame. Call `setBorder(..)` on that panel using an `EmptyBorder` as the argument passed to the method.

For example:

```
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
```